# "MissingRegistered" Lint warnings when using com.google.android.material.* UI components

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gradle-plugin, material-design, lint

I'm trying to get rid of the Lint warnings in my Android project. Doing so I run into the following type of warning messages that I do not understand:

```
app\src\main\res\layout-land\event_settings_fragment.xml:25: Error: Class referenced in the layout file, com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout, was not found in the project or the libraries [MissingRegistered]
      <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
      ^
```

My app seems to be running fine, so the `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout` class should be available in the project?
Note that I do get this warning on all `com.google.android.material.*` classes.

Answer (score 0):

> ### MissingRegistered
>
> Summary: Missing registered class
>
> Priority: 8 / 10
>   Severity: Error
>
> Category: Correctness
>
> NOTE: This issue is disabled by default!
>
> You can enable it by adding --enable MissingRegistered
>
> If a class is referenced in the manifest or in a layout file, it must also
>   exist in the project (or in one of the libraries included by the project. This
>   check helps uncover typos in registration names, or attempts to rename or move
>   classes without updating the manifest file properly.
>
> See: http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks

If you ensure that the layout file runs without problems, you can disable the check:

```
app/build.gradle

android{
    lintOptions{
        disable "MissingRegistered"
    }
}
```

or add `tools:ignore="MissingRegistered"` in the layout file to suppress the check.